# RFID reading / sniffing demonstration at a live-event

Tags: antenna, rfid, hacking

In the context of a live-event, we want to demonstrate how easy it is for someone with the right equipment to sniff RFID devices, including clear-text information.

Our idea is to **hide a RFID reader with an antenna (up to 40cm) inside a common object** such as a coffee machine or a trash, and to invite people to come by, then at the end of the presentation we would show what the reader has found, hopefully containing a bunch of personally identifiable information (e.g. name, address, ID).

*Please note that everyone attending this event will be told beforehand we are going to do something like that, and every one will have the possibility to "opt-out" for this demonstration. At the end of the event, the data gathered will be completely wiped.*

The device would have to understand the most common protocols used for every day RFID tags (as far as I understand, that would be MIFARE and a couple ISO standard protocols), to increase our chance to collect visible (i.e. clear-text, *demonstrable*) information.

I'm used to programming (C/Python mostly), but I have a very little electronics experience, and more importantly, I won't have time to go for a DIY project. I need a **ready-to-use solution** (although I already plan to code a bit in order to extract the results and put them in shape automatically so that I can directly present the results with a nice layout).

**My question is:** which hardware would you recommend for this project ? I have parsed hundred of products, online shops and forums, but I can't get a clear idea of what I need. And, from your experience, what are your recommendations for such an event ?

PS: If my question is too "vendor-oriented", please answer with generic devices requirements I have to check, like the protocols it must support, type of antenna, etc.

Comment: RFID smart cards rarely contain any personal information. And when they do, they are well secured.

Comment: I doubt my local car-washer encrypts anything on my card (sensible data, such as credit, is stored server-side), same for my dry cleaner, gym etc. A simple ID number *is* a personal information, it doesn't have to be a social security number or other really sensitive stuff. If you have examples of basic but yet "well secured" RFID cards, I'll take it though.

Comment: Most rfid tags contain one thing. An ID number. Thats it.

Comment: @Passerby: Thank you for the information. Would you have an idea of what else could be done from an RFID security point-of-view then ? Or would you think this is a dead-end for the demonstration purpose (I doubt an ID number would create the wow-effect we're looking for).

Comment: I agree that nobody would really care about showing them only UIDs from the tags. Most cards that contain personal information use at least the built in security features of the tag. Some systems put a security layer on top of that. And even if you have access to a card and you are able to read the data, you would still have to figure out how to interpret it. Maybe you are lucky and read out some clear text ASCII information (like a name) but it is unlikely. I think without carefully investigating a lot of common tags beforehand you won't have much to show.

Comment: @Rev1.0 Thank you. I'm going to rethink this idea then.

Comment: In your first sentence you said this was easy...  Go back to your source of that little bit of information and find out how they did it?  You'll need an RFID reader or two, depending on your band of interest as well as an antenna for each reader.  Then read up on the API for each reader and code a simple solution that grabs the tag data.  Look for autonomous mode or something like that.  But as other commenters have already said, there's probably little of interest unless it's a passport or passcard they're carrying.